# Парсер для json на flask

Tags: flask, python, json, sqlalchemy, postgresql

Как пропарсить json файл flask-ом и записать его в БД кириллицей. Если он вот таком формате:

```
{"data": [{"\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c": "\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e-     \u0424\u0440\u0430\u043d\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f",     "\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434": "\u041a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0440-    \u043d", "\u0417\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435": "288.00"}, 
....]
  "structure": ["\u041e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c",     "\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", "\u0417\u043d\u0430\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435"]}
```

Comment: Для каких целей вы хотите записать содержимое json файла в БД? Ваш файл, который вы хотите импортировать, имеет определенную структуру или может быть любым? Уточните.

Comment: К примеру, есть json файл, внутри он имеет такую вот структуру: группа (Область), параметр (Город) и значение. В общем, имеет определенную структуру.

Хочу построить график зависимости.

Comment: Так в чем вы видите проблему парсинга JSON и нужно ли вам вообще писать его в базу? Так же вы не уточняете, нужно это сделать один раз или данные будут добавляться переодически.

Comment: Пока что один раз. Ну вот учусь и решил придумать такое себе задание.

Comment: JSON парсить очень просто. https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html тут все навписано.

Comment: Эту док. я читал, спасибо.